# Mail.app stopped working after upgrade to OS X Mavericks

Tags: mail.app, macos

Mail.app is not working since the upgrade to OS X Mavericks. I read that I should try to uncheck SSL. However it won't let me. All my emails just sit in the outbox. Is there a way to remedy this or is there another mail software I can download?

I'm using Gmail which I know has types of issues and have accepted that but it's my business POP emails that is frustrating me.

Comment: It would be useful if you edit your question and specify which mail you're using (like iCloud, Gmail, Yahoo, etc.) and also include screenshots of the settings that you say you cannot change.

Comment: And whether the accounts you are checking are set up for POP or IMAP.

Comment: Are you using 2 Step Authentication in Gmail? Then what if you generate a new application specific password and use that for the Gmail SMTP server?

Answer (score 1):

I've switched to Postbox for my mail client until some of the Apple Mail glitches get worked out. Postbox seems to be built on the Thunderbird engine (which also works well) but it adds additional features. I use multiple Gmail and IMAP accounts, but I don't currently use any POP accounts -- based on past experience with Thunderbird I wouldn't expect any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Suffered the same pains as you, I think, when upgrading my machines to Mavericks, especially with gmail accounts. I solved my problems by moving all the gmail accounts to the AirMail client. It is good, it has a modern look (it did cost me a couple(! :-) ) of bucks on the App Store), with a lot functionality and it is being actively maintained. They have a stable version for sale on the App Store, but also a Beta channel that is as good and gets more frequent fixes (I use their Beta version). I never looked back.

Answer (score 0):

When I do major system upgrade, I configure clean system to have no waste in new one. I use Mail.app for Gmail and other mailboxes without any issues (all connections are SSL).

Answer (score -1):

As an alternative email client, you can try [Thunderbird](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/). It supports many features Mail.app lacks but it's not as polished for OSX as Mail.